# Quarkus using Apache Camel: MockEndpoint not working

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus, junit5

I am using Apache Camel with Quarkus and I have some `@QuarkusTest` that use `@MockEndpoint` that stop to work after I upgraded from camel quarkus 2.7.0 to 2.16.0.

The tests look like:

```java
@QuarkusTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class SuperTest {

    @Inject
    CamelContext context;

    @EndpointInject("mock:aSpecialEndpoint")
    MockEndpoint mockEndpoint;

    @BeforeAll
    void setup() throws Exception {
        AdviceWith.adviceWith(context, "route-id",
                route -> route.weaveById("aSpecialEndpoint").replace().to(mockEndpoint)
        );
    }

    @AfterEach
    void clear() {
        System.out.println("After each");
        mockEndpoint.reset();
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("method")
    void firstTest(String param1, String expectedResult) throws InterruptedException {

        mockEndpoint.whenAnyExchangeReceived(exchange -> exchange.getMessage().setBody(
          new SpecialObject(param1))
        );

        // rest assured call to the endpoint...

        mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        mockEndpoint.expectedHeaderValuesReceivedInAnyOrder("id", "AAA");
        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

}
```

I skipped the method source and the endpoint call, I can also guarantee that the id is correct. In fact, the test runs and works, the only bit that has a different behavior is the call to `mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied()`.

What happens is that the test runs, `after each` is called, then the `assertIsSatisfied` logs a WARN: `The latch did not reach 0 within the specified time`. It has indeed done the assetions, but it has waited 10 seconds to do so (10 seconds is the default value). Consequently, the build becomes super slow.

I tried to use the overloaded method `assertIsSatisfied(long)` to assign a timeout, but if set it to 0, the test fails, if I set it to anything else, I got the same error as above.

What can I do?